# Unable to log into account on mySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a world of trouble trying to get the website I'm making's accounts to log in. I'm using PHP to log access an SQL database on a raspberry pi. And it's working. I can make accounts; however, I can't log into them.

I'm using code from [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html)

I'm tweaked the names but most of it is the same. As for my database named Users, it's simply an ID(int), username(varchar) and password(char) in a table named users. Here is my code for the login page that sends the information to login_submission.

Here is the Login Page

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Login Here</h2>
<form action="login_submit.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<p>
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" maxlength="20" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="20" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Login_submission page:

```php
<?php

/*** begin our session ***/
session_start();

/*** check if the users is already logged in ***/
if(isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ))
{
    $message = 'Users is already logged in';
}
/*** check that both the username, password have been submitted ***/
if(!isset( $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
{
    $message = 'Please enter a valid username and password';
}
/*** check the username is the correct length ***/
elseif (strlen( $_POST['username']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['username']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Length for Username';
}
/*** check the password is the correct length ***/
elseif (strlen( $_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Length for Password';
}
/*** check the username has only alpha numeric characters ***/
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['username']) != true)
{
    /*** if there is no match ***/
    $message = "Username must be alpha numeric";
}
/*** check the password has only alpha numeric characters ***/
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['password']) != true)
{
        /*** if there is no match ***/
        $message = "Password must be alpha numeric";
}
else
{
    /*** if we are here the data is valid and we can insert it into database ***/
    $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    /*** now we can encrypt the password ***/
    $password = sha1( $password );

    /*** connect to database ***/
    /*** mysql hostname ***/
    $mysql_hostname = 'localhost';

    /*** mysql username ***/
    $mysql_username = 'root';

    /*** mysql password ***/
    $mysql_password = 'raspberry';

    /*** database name ***/
    $mysql_dbname = 'Users';

    try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
        /*** $message = a message saying we have connected ***/

        /*** set the error mode to excptions ***/
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        /*** prepare the select statement ***/
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user_id, username, password FROM users 
                    WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");

        /*** bind the parameters ***/
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

        /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
        $stmt->execute();

        /*** check for a result ***/
        $user_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        /*** if we have no result then fail boat ***/
        if($user_id == false)
        {
                $message = 'Login Failed';
        }
        /*** if we do have a result, all is well ***/
        else
        {
                /*** set the session user_id variable ***/
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

                /*** tell the user we are logged in ***/
                $message = 'You are now logged in';
        }


    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database ***/
        $message = 'We are unable to process your request. Please try again later"';
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>PHPRO Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><?php echo $message; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is `mysql` running on localhost? Have you tried without a password?

Comment: What error(s) are you seeing, exactly? This would help a lot.

Comment: Please give the error you are getting. Thanks

Comment: `var_dump($e)` in your catch block might be helpful.

Comment: Two things immediately come to mind: 1) if the first condition is true you can skip the rest   2) the `$message` needs to be additive. You can have multiple conditions valid simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

For the Record, I was able to get it to work! I worked till 5am trying to get the problem fixed last night. Then, I woke up this morning and fixed it within ten minutes. Fresh eyes, I suppose.

Anyways, for anyone looking to use this code, my problem was that my query was searching for user_id's in a column named `user_id` when the actual column name is `id`.

To use this code for yourself, create the same database/table I have.

`CREATE DATABASE Users;`

`USE Users;`

`CREATE TABLE users (id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, username varchar(20) NOT NULL, password char(40) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE KEY (username));`

You'll be good to go. 
Let em know if anyone wants me to post the add user portions with these variables. Or you can find the original code in the link above. (going to have to change the variables. DON'T MISS THE ID FIELD LIKE I DID.)

Thank you all,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I recently used for an admin-login page for a small website I'm writing at the moment. It's basically the same procedure for creating user logins. You just need to connect to the the users database or users table instead of admins and redirect to users profile page (you make one, like an admin page) when authentication is successful. If you've got the time to play around a little you can test it on xampp.

Here is the link: http://www.intechgrity.com/login-logout-and-administrate-using-php-session-cookie-mysql-version-2-with-remember-me-option/#

It's also a nice tutorial on how to build a simple admin-login page.

This is not a perfect answer to your problem but some parts from this project might help a little.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to check it out. This project is due tonight so I won't have time to change it but I'll definitely look into working with it later! -Peter